# Twitter Top Tweets like jQuery Plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter

I'm looking for a JavaScript or a jQuery plugin has an effect like the twitter top tweets. Thanks in advance.

http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/6899/twitterl.jpg

Comment: What specific functionality are you looking for? What code do you already have?

Comment: In twitter home page in the middle there is a top tweets scrolling block. I’m looking for a script that can make the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.amitpatil.me/twitter-like-top-tweet-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

Its a very simple effect. You can do it yourself by following [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/create-a-twitter-like-load-more-widget/).

Comment: Im not looking for load more. im looking for a scrolling plugin just like in twitter home page

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't read your comment. I guess this one is not as simple.

Answer (score 1):

Hi guy you find this type of plugin here

http://www.amitpatil.me/tweeter-like-top-tweet-jquery-plugin/